# How far am I from the unsung hero badge?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer, zero-score-badges

When I ran [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i) query, it is giving me this result:

```
Accepted Answers     Scored Answers    Unscored Answers     Percentage Unscored
35                   26                9                    25.7
```

But when I count from answers tab, I have 42 accepted answers, out of which 27 are scored and 15 unscored. Of course 2 are self-accepted answers. Even then why this much difference? How far am I from the unsung hero badge?

Comment: SEDE isn't updated real time; the data reflected in there is likely different than what you're observing at this moment.

Comment: Here is a working query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The Data Explorer is only updated once a week. You're seeing data as the site existed on September 1, 2013 at 08:08:29 UTC, when it was last updated.
2. Only answers which are at least 10 days old are considered for the badge.
3. Community wiki and self-accepted answers (as well as deleted answers) do not count.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the difference in the query and your "manual" counting is due to the fact that the database is only updated once every week. Some of those answers are probably from within the past week.

As long as those answers remain unscored you should receive the unsung hero badge ten days after the tenth accepted unscored answer was accepted.